# no disparity output of stereo_image_proc

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ROS Electric on Ubuntu 11.10 x86 with Linux kernel 3.0.0-16-generic-pae and
I'm experiencing almost the same problem as in thread:[No-disparity-on-output-of-stereo_image_proc](http://answers.ros.org/question/11769/no-disparity-on-output-of-stereo_image_proc). I'm using a pair of PointGrey Chameleon cameras, and I get both left and right rectified mono and color topic at 15Hz, verified with rostopic hz and image_view on the following topics:

```
/stereo/left/image_rect
/stereo/right/image_rect
/stereo/left/image_mono
/stereo/right/image_mono
/stereo/left/image_raw
/stereo/right/image_raw
/stereo/left/image_color
/stereo/right/image_color
```

I'm running stereo_image_proc with _approximate_sync:=True parameter but the problem is I'm getting no messages on /stereo/disparity topic. Can anyone help me solve this issue? I know there were a few facing almost the same problem, but I can't manage to find a correct solution to this problem, other than using __approximate_sync=true.

I'm using a launch file to run stereo_image_proc in the same namespace as the camera drivers, that look something like this:

```
<launch> 
<group ns="stereo" >
<!-- left camera -->
<node pkg="camera1394" type="camera1394_node" name="left" >
 <param name="guid" value="00b09d01009a2931" />
  <param name="video_mode" value="1280x960_mono8" />
  <param name="iso_speed" value="400" />
  <param name="frame_id" value="camera_left" />
  <param name="frame_rate" value="15" />
  <param name="bayer_pattern" value="gbrg" />
  <param name="bayer_method" value="" />
  <param name="camera_info_url" value="file:///home/robo/.ros/camera_info/00b09d01009a2931.yaml" />
  <remap from="camera" to="left" />
 </node>
 <!-- right camera -->
 <node pkg="camera1394" type="camera1394_node" name="right">
<param name="guid" value="00b09d01009a290e" />
  <param name="video_mode" value="1280x960_mono8" />
  <param name="iso_speed" value="400" />
  <param name="frame_id" value="camera_right" />
  <param name="frame_rate" value="15" />
  <param name="bayer_pattern" value="gbrg" />
  <param name="bayer_method" value="" />
  <param name="camera_info_url" value="file:///home/robo/.ros/camera_info/00b09d01009a290e.yaml" />
   <remap from="camera" to="right" />
   </node>
<node pkg="stereo_image_proc" type="stereo_image_proc" respawn="false" name="stereo_image_proc" args="_approximate_sync:=True">
</node>
```

The same thing happens if I don't run stereo_image_proc in the launch file, but instead I use the command:
ROS_NAMESPACE=stereo rosrun stereo_image_proc stereo_image_proc __name:=proc __approximate_sync:=True

In both cases I'm getting rectified color images from both cameras (inspected with image_view)

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29380/no-disparity-output-of-stereo_image_proc/) by [Robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1927/robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) on 2012-03-09**:
please also post the exact command you use to run stereo_image_proc

**Comment by [Robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1927/robo/) on 2012-03-12**:
It seems that I cannot comment on your answer: I've tried that and a couple of other things. To me, the situation looks like this: stere_image_proc is conected (tested with rxgraph as well) to the right topics and is publising rectified images. The issue is with disparity and pointcloud topics

**Comment by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) on 2015-09-22**:
Robo -- which part of Bences solution worked for you? I'm having a similar problem. I can see the rectified output images, but not a disparity image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_NAMESPACE=stereo rosrun stereo_image_proc stereo_image_proc /stereo/left/image_raw:=/stereo/left/image /stereo/right/image_raw:=/stereo/right/image

Sorry but based on these I don't have the direct solution.
I used to run the command above because I only have that 2 image topics in my datasets.

Also there are some packages that sometimes won't get the topic namespace right if you put it like this: "ROS_NAMESPACE=stereo" but using this works: "ROS_NAMESPACE=/stereo" -- although as it can be seen it's working for me in this case

To check if the data flow is right I used to use rxgraph with all_topics checked.
That's all the hints I could give you, good luck :)

---

Originally posted by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) with karma: 358 on 2012-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1